# How to use Fn keys in tmux?

Tags: vim, tmux

I have a bind in vim for `F5` key to trim whitespaces and I'm unable to use it in tmux.
Instead of that letter "T" appears. Is there's any solution for that?

Actually it was working in putty, now I've switched to Xshell4.
Can this be TERM issue? inside tmux `$TERM` is `screen`

Comment: related: [How do I make the F-keys work in byobu, for midnight commander (mc), htop, etc?](https://askubuntu.com/q/146585/3712)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does you `.tmux.conf` contain any lines that set `default-terminal`?

Assuming Xshell4 emulates xterm (check that `$TERM` is `xterm` within your shell *outside of tmux*...

Then try adding the following to your `.tmux.conf`

```
# xterm-style function key sequences
setw -g xterm-keys on
```

Also check what the `term` and `ttytype` variables are *within* Vim (inside tmux).

Comment: You mean $TERM?

Comment: No. I mean term. In vim try :set term?